# Why is NASM acting weird on this simple code?

Tags: assembly, nasm

My code is just a simple "operating system" where I do nothing but the bare basics. Here's the code:

```asm
;boot.asm: The entry point of PizzaOS
jmp $ ;Jump to the current instruction, aka infinite loop
times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0x00 ;We only have 512 bytes to keep the bootsector. Fill up the remaining space with empty data. Since the magic number is 2 bytes, 512 - 2 = 510
dw 0xAA55 ;Define word, magic number
```

I am compiling it with `nasm "D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm"`. I have already uninstalled and re-installed the latest version of `nasm`.

But it gives me this gigantic error message (**the code isn't 300 lines, the above box has everything**):

```
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:1: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:3: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:4: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:5: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:6: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:7: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:8: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:9: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:10: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:11: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:13: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:14: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:15: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:17: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:18: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:19: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:20: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:21: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:23: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:24: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:25: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:26: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:27: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:29: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:30: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:32: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:33: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:34: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:35: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:36: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:37: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:38: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:43: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:44: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:45: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:47: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:50: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:51: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:52: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:53: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:55: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:56: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:58: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:59: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:60: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:62: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:63: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:64: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:65: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:66: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:67: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:68: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:70: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:71: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:72: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:73: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:74: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:75: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:76: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:77: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:78: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:79: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:80: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:81: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:83: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:84: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:85: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:87: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:88: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:89: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:90: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:91: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:92: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:93: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:94: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:96: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:97: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:98: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:99: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:104: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:105: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:106: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:107: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:108: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:110: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:111: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:112: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:114: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:116: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:117: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:119: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:121: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:122: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:123: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:125: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:126: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:128: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:129: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:130: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:131: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:134: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:135: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:137: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:138: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:139: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:140: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:142: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:143: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:144: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:145: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:147: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:148: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:149: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:151: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:152: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:153: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:154: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:155: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:157: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:158: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:160: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:161: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:162: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:163: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:165: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:166: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:167: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:169: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:170: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:171: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:172: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:173: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:174: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:175: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:176: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:177: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:178: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:179: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:181: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:182: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:183: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:184: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:186: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:187: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:189: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:190: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:191: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:193: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:194: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:195: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:196: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:197: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:198: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:199: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:200: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:201: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:203: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:204: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:205: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:206: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:207: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:209: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:210: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:211: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:212: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:214: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:215: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:216: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:217: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:218: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:220: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:221: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:222: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:223: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:224: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:226: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:227: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:228: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:229: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:230: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:232: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:233: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:234: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:236: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:237: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:238: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:239: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:240: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:242: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:243: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:244: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:245: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:246: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:247: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:249: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:250: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:252: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:254: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:255: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:256: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:257: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:258: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:259: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:261: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:262: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:263: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:265: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:267: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:269: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:271: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:272: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:273: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:278: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:279: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:281: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:282: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:283: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:284: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:285: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:286: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:289: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:290: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:291: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:292: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:293: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:294: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:296: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:297: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:298: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:299: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:300: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:302: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:303: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:304: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:305: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:306: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:308: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:309: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:310: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:311: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:312: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
D:\PizzaOS\src\boot.asm:313: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
```

What's happening here? (I tried compiling it without the comments; The only difference was that it produced less error messages, but it still did not compile).

Comment: After pasting your code block into a file, `nasm -fbin boot.asm` assembles it without complaint (NASM 2.15.05 on Arch Linux).  You must be assembling something else.  Maybe try `nasm boot.asm -l boot.lst` to have it output a listing file, where you can see what input it was reading.

Comment: Thank you, I will try `-fbin ` and the listing option when I get back on my laptop tomorrow. I’ll post an answer if it works for me (Windows 11 x64). Also by script I meant code, lol (edited question)

Comment: `-fbin` is the default; `nasm boot.asm` also works.  It's just habit for me to make it explicit.

Comment: Perhaps you are saving your file as some sort of UTF-16 ?

Comment: I will check when I get back home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah yes. UTF-16 was the issue. All I had to do was re-save the file in UTF-8, and now it works! Yay!